# Three equations in two columns

Tags: math-mode, align, matrices

I have a large matrix with 2 small matrices and I try to align it in the following way:

[image]

I had like matrix C to be under B instead of in a new row.

The code now is:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c  c }\hspace*{-1.5cm}
$A^{T}(t)=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\       
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\        
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\        
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\   
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\tau} & 0 \\  
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\tau} \\                      
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
B^{T}(t)=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\tau} & 0 \\   
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\tau} \\
\end{bmatrix}$
\\
\\
$C(t)=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why exactly do you use a tabular, if you do not use it? And please make your example compilable.

Comment: the tabular is there because B is in a different column, however not sure hot to make 2 rows in 1 column while in the other there is only 1 row.

Comment: You did NOT put B in a different column (`\qquad` is just space, no different column). If you'd put it into the second column you could put C below, e.g. using the `multirow` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still 70pt too wide, but you haven't said how wide your page is, so perhaps it may work...

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}

\begin{document}

something
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}
A^{T}(t)=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\       
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\        
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\        
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\   
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\tau} & 0 \\  
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\tau} \\                      
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{aligned}
B^{T}(t)&=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\tau} & 0 \\   
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\tau} \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
C(t)&=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless either your document's text block is unusually wide or you're willing to use a very small font size, it's not likely that the matrix expressions for `B` and `C` will fit to the right of the expression for `A`

I would use a simple `align*` environment to typeset the three matrices, one below the other.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{13}
\newcommand\trans{^{T\mkern-5mu}} % transpose oper.

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A\trans(t) &=
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\       
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\        
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\        
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\   
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\tau} & 0 \\  
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\tau} \\                      
\end{bmatrix*} \\
B\trans(t) &=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\tau} & 0 \\   
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\tau} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
C(t) &=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It hardly fits text width. I can do it using the `mmatrix` environment from `nccmath` (medium-sized matrices), reducing the value of `\arraycolsep` and loading `geometry` to have more a sensible outer margin. I also used the `bmatrix*` environment fom `mathtools`, which accepts an optional argument for the alignment of the columns (in my opinion, right-aligned looks better, due to the `—` signs in some columns):

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath, bigstrut}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}

    \begin{document}

\[ \setlength{\arraycolsep}{5pt}
  A^{T}(t) =
\begin{mmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \bigstrut[t]\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \mathllap{-\mkern-1.5mu}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \mathllap{-\mkern-1.5mu}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \mathllap{-\mkern-1.5mu}\frac{1}{\tau} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \mathllap{-\mkern-1.5mu}\frac{1}{\tau}\bigstrut[b] \\
\end{bmatrix*}
\end{mmatrix}
\quad
 \begin{aligned}
B^{T}(t) & =
\begin{mmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\tau} & 0 \bigstrut[t]\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\tau} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{mmatrix}
\\
\\
C(t) & =
\begin{mmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \bigstrut[t]
\end{bmatrix}
\end{mmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did what you supposed to want using `array` instead of `bmatrix` + `tabular`.
By the way, if you use these three matrix with the default font size of LaTeX, the paper margins have to be reduced.
I used:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=5mm,top=5mm,bottom=5mm,right=5mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

$A^{T}(t)=\left[\begin{array}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\       
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\        
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\        
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\   
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\tau} & 0 \\  
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\tau} \\  
\end{array}\right]
\qquad
\begin{array}{l} {B^{T}(t)= \left[\begin{array}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\tau} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\tau}  \end{array}\right]} \\
\\
{C(t)=\left[\begin{array}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]} \end{array}$

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The result was:

[image]